# How do you add jquery animation to mvc 2 rendered controls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

have an editor template that can be rendered 0 to n times on a given page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<NewEmployee.Models.RequestedAccessViewModel>" %>
<fieldset style="display: inline;">
    <legend>
        <%: Model.Description %></legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requested) %>
        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Requested)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments) %>
    </div>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Description) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) %>
</fieldset>
```

What I'd really like is the 'Comments' text area to be hidden initially, and slide down into view when the check box is hit, and slide back out if the checkbox is turned off again.

I know how I would do this with traditinal asp.net, but am at a loss with MVC2.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I know I need to select the checkboxs to add the event, but then how do I make sure that the event does animation to the specific text area, not all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a jQuery function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div.editor-field").hide();

    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {

         if ($(this).attr("checked")) {

              $("div.editor-field").show();                
         }
         else {
              $("div.editor-field").hide();
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Unfortuanly this does exactly what I was afraid of, it toggles all the text areas on the screen, not just the one on the same editor template as the check box :(

Comment: If you want to hide a particular text area only; you can simply give id of that textarea/container div like $("#id_of_your_control").hide();

Comment: How do you determine the Id of the control that will be rendering using one of the Html.<x>For(...) helper functions?

Comment: Check the html source of the page once it rendered; generally id of the control will be your model property name